# Android media projection produces an empty movie file

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-mediacodec, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to create a simple screencast app which would capture the screen and the save to a movie file. So far my application has been producing only empty movie files(black screen) of correct length and size. I'm not sure if this helps but when I'm running the application I get these messages in logcat

```
08-29 14:47:57.722    1973-1991/com.example.stw.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-29 14:47:57.722    1973-1991/com.example.stw.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdbee60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-29 14:47:58.870    1973-1991/com.example.stw.myapplication E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab659760
08-29 14:47:58.875    1973-1991/com.example.kamil.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xab32c580 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0xa333d8d0
08-29 14:48:00.652    1973-1973/com.example.kamil.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Video track stopping
08-29 14:48:00.652    1973-1973/com.example.kamil.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Video track source stopping
08-29 14:48:00.652    1973-1973/com.example.kamil.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Video track source stopped
```

Other than that the messages seem irrelevant.
I'll post some of the code maybe it will help.
I get the surface

```
mInputSurface = mVideoEncoder.createInputSurface();
```

So i'm creating virtual display:

```
        mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("Recording Display", screenWidth,
            screenHeight, screenDensity, 0 /* flags */, mInputSurface,
            null /* callback */, null /* handler */);
```

Then this method gets called:

```
    private void prepareVideoEncoder() {
    mVideoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    int frameRate = 30; // 30 fps

    // Set some required properties. The media codec may fail if these aren't defined.
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 6000000); // 6Mbps
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CAPTURE_RATE, frameRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER, 1000000 / frameRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1); // 1 seconds between I-frames

    // Create a MediaCodec encoder and configure it. Get a Surface we can use for recording into.
    try {
        mVideoEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE);
        mVideoEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mInputSurface = mVideoEncoder.createInputSurface();
        mVideoEncoder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseEncoders();
    }
}
```

Then when the user clicks stop recording i release encoders like below:

```
    private void releaseEncoders() {
    mDrainHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrainEncoderRunnable);
    if (mMuxer != null) {
        if (mMuxerStarted) {
            mMuxer.stop();
        }
        mMuxer.release();
        mMuxer = null;
        mMuxerStarted = false;
    }
    if (mVideoEncoder != null) {
        mVideoEncoder.stop();
        mVideoEncoder.release();
        mVideoEncoder = null;
    }
    if (mInputSurface != null) {
        mInputSurface.release();
        mInputSurface = null;
    }
    if (mMediaProjection != null) {
        mMediaProjection.stop();
        mMediaProjection = null;
    }
    mVideoBufferInfo = null;
    mDrainEncoderRunnable = null;
    mTrackIndex = -1;
}
```

Thanks for help. Hopefully you guys will be able to spot something I've missed.

Comment: If your description is true, you should be crashing with a `NullPointerException` somewhere. You indicate that you call `mVideoEncoder.createInputSurface()` before `prepareVideoEncoder()`, but it is in `prepareVideoEncoder()` where you are populating `mVideoEncoder`. I haven't played with screen recording, just the screenshots. However, Jake Wharton's Telecine does not use `MediaCodec`, but instead uses `MediaRecorder`: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine/blob/master/telecine/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/telecine/RecordingSession.java

Comment: Ahh sorry my question was a bit misleading I use mVideoEncoder.createInputSurface() in method prepareVideoEncoder() only , I don't know why I inserted this first line there.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing similar issue

Comment: Yes this was simply because it will not work on emulators, test your app on a real device and it should work. Apparently the video encoding on emulators does not work properly yet.

Comment: Does this work for encoding at full screen resolution? I heard that MediaCodec is too slow and MediaRecorder should be used.

Comment: I've found that mediaRecorder is slower than MediaCodec